# NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

Could someone smart explain me please where I have a bug?

I get this error when I would like to send a profile user form

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: userprofile_userprofile.godzina_id
```

[image: It looks like this:]

I have an app "userprofile"

forms.py
    from django import forms
    from models import UserProfile

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('imie', 'godzina')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from forms import UserProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.conf import settings

@login_required
def user_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
    else:
        user = request.user
        profile = user.profile
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = form
        return render(request, 'user_profile.html', args)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from godzina.models import Godzina

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    imie = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    godzina = models.ForeignKey('godzina.Godzina')   


User.profile = property(lambda u:UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add `null=True` to your `godzina` attribute:

```
godzina = models.ForeignKey('godzina.Godzina', null=True)
```

Comment: @user3904216 (just to make sure) Did you do `syncdb`/`migrate` to save changes in the table's schema?